# Electromagnetic waves highest frequency and beyond?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

If an electromagnetic waves frequency is generated by the change of voltage / current in a wire  or a atom decaying to get gamma waves.

What is the highest frequency possible give the faster the change in voltage/currect the higher frequencies generate?

So as the frequency goes up and as the change in voltage/current becomes instant, (if possibe) what is the state on the wave between the upper and lower limits of the wave? Is this a state possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when the frequency of A.C becomes infinite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95339/)

Comment: FWIW: Long before you get to gamma radiation, you are talking about frequencies that we have no way to measure. People say, "frequency" when they're talking about radio waves. As you go up the spectrum, frequency gradually becomes less interesting, and "wavelength" gradually takes over. In the infrared and optical region, it's pretty much all "wavelength," but as you go further still, there's a similar transition from "wavelength" to "energy."

Comment: Have you heard of the GZK-limit? The energy of a photon is reference frame dependent.